# i can't return encapsulated data on java

Tags: java, compiler-errors

i get this error message when i run my program in java`your text
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "Tables.getStatus()" because "" is null
at program.tableDraw(program.java:31)
at program.main(program.java:14)

```
public class program{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Tables[][] gameTable = new Tables[3][3];
        for(Tables[] tables : gameTable){
            for(Tables table : tables){
                table = new Tables();
                System.out.println(table.getStatus());//->i get a return value
            }
        }
        tableDraw(gameTable);
    }
    static void tableDraw(Tables[][] gameTable){
        if(gameTable.length != 3 && gameTable[0].length != 3) {
            System.out.println("game table created wrong");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        for(Tables[] tables : gameTable){
            System.out.println();
            for(Tables table : tables){
                char c = '.';
                Tables.status stat = table.getStatus();//->java.lang.NullPointerException occur          
                if(stat == Tables.status.x) c = 'x';
                else if(stat == Tables.status.o) c = 'o';
                System.out.print(c);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Tables class and methods

```
public class Tables {
public enum status{
        blank,
        x,
        o
    }
    private status stat;
    Tables(){
        this.stat = status.blank;
    }
public status getStatus(){
        return this.stat;
    }
}
```

i searched whole internet for find solution, they were saying this error happen when you return null. But i entered a value before i try return it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```java
    for(Tables table : tables) {
        table = new Tables();
    }
```

will **not** set the cells of `tables` - an enhanced for loop (for-each) is not suitable to change the array.

The `tables` array will still be filled with default values, that is, with `null`. Further on, calling `getStatus()` from `null` throws the `NullPointerException`.

You will need to assign to the array like in `tables[i] = new Tables();`

Recommended to (learn and to) use a debugger - that problem should be relatively easy to spot using one.

Answer (score 0):

Your `this.stat` is private. Make it public. You cannot return a private variable.

Comment: You sure can return a `private` variable! You cannot access a `private` field from **outside** the class; but the code of the class can access its own fields. Returning the value of private fields is one of the main concepts of Encapsulation/Object-Oriented-Programming. And access *violations* result in compilation errors, not NullPointerException (a runtime error)

Comment: So why is the exception occuring?

Comment: because the code is trying to call `getStatus()` from a `null` reference: `gameTable` is not initialized, that is, full of `null`, see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78004257/85421)

Comment: see [Declaring Member Variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html) from *The Java™ Tutorials* if you don't believe me! (for example the method `getCadence()` is returning a `private` variable)